# How can I add spaces in PHP?

Tags: php, whitespace

```
echo "student id, emirate name <br>";
foreach ($resultset as $row)
echo $row['st_id'],  "" , $row['em_name'],'<br />';
```

My question is: How can I add more spaces between st_id and em_ name? Because when I tried to run the page the information are very close to each other. I tried the quotation mark " " between them, but it just adds one space.

Comment: `echo $row['st_id'],  " " , $row['em_name'], " ",  $row['st_bday'], " ",  $row['st_emirate'] , " ",  $row['em_id'], " ",  $row['em_name'],'<br />';`

Comment: Do you value the time and effort of people that are going to help you out with your problem? If somebody spends 10 minutes of their time trying to understand your question and answer it in a way that you can understand, will you be grateful? If so (and I'd be surprised if you said no) then why can't you put the same amount of effort in to formatting your question nicely, spelling and fixing your English? What comes around goes around.

Comment: Is this question for real or is someone taking the mickey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're echoing this to a browser, in which case,  & nbsp;

must be used.

```
echo $row['st_id'],  "&nbsp;&nbsp;" , $row['em_name'], " ",  $row['st_bday'], "",  $row['st_emirate'] , "",  $row['em_id'], "&nbsp;",  $row['em_name'],'<br />';
```

Comment: it doesn't need `&nbsp;` if hes echoing only 1 space, browser don't allow multi spaces, in case of only 1 space simply use `" "`

Comment: Nobody's fault - the question is incredibly unclear.

Comment: @xYuri  I want to add more than one space I used " " but it only add one space .